# Unable to queue build error with Azure DevOps Pull Request

Tags: azure, azure-devops, pull-request

I want to trigger a build before pull request starts for merging (in Azure DevOps). For this option, I have added the Build validation under branch policies. But if I created a new Pull Request, I am getting the message as "Unable to queue build".

Please anyone let me know the option I selected solves my requirement. If yes, how to solve this "Unable to queue build" issue. If no, any option available to achieve my requirement.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more context for the error scenario, such as any elaboration in the pull request? - perhaps the build you reference requires variable input which could be missing in the pull request scenario?

Comment: Hi @Kattesang. Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answers could give you some help. Just a remind of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: @TimonYang - your response matched my case. Setting up a pull request build validation should be done on the targeted merging repository. I'm having a forked repo in ADO with goal to queue validation builds prior merge, and the main repository should be used as source for the build. Setting up PR build validation automatically uses the incoming files as its source.

Comment: I forgot I had disabled the pipeline, so it wouldn't run.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem and i changed the branch policy to include the build pipeline:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser

Branch policy could be found from:

- Repos -> Branches
- Click on the 3 dots to the right of the branch that the PR is going to.

[image: Actual branch policy]

[image: Add build policy]

Comment: This was actually the solution. I created a new pipeline with a yml file and when I wanted to run the build pipeline on an already exisiting PR, the build did not queue. When I checked the develop branch settings, it seems like the repo removed the pipeline name (the older name). That is why it was not able to queue.

Comment: This was it for me too -  not because the policy didn't exist, but rather I needed to select the new pipeline within the existing policy.

Answer (score 9):

Your options is achievable, and the problem now is most likely caused by you triggering the pipeline in the wrong repository.

For example, if you create a pipeline from repository 1 and trigger the pipeline in a pull request created from repository 2, the pipeline will not be queued.

Modify your pipeline or PR repository so that the pipeline and PR use the same repository, this should be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem, checking pipeline for being disabled or edited anyhow, but no differences.

But by checking the linked work items (tasks/pbis), I saw that one or more had not been completed. After changing the states everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the reason was that the source branch was deleted