# Unable to queue PR Validation

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I created a pull request in Azure DevOps but the build was not started, it says "Required Check broken, ***Unable to queue PR Validation***"

Any idea, how this could be resolved. Previously the build used to start automatically but this time it did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a policy requiring PR changes to build successfully before the PR can complete.

The  pipeline and the pull request pipeline should be created from same repositories if not you will face an error "Unable to queue PR validation."

Please find the [Build Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#build-validation) document and the related [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65087322) for complete information.